# How to run Python debugger for a Python console application which raises an exception

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

If I start `ipython notebook` from the command line IPython throws an exception with a long traceback and I want to run a debugger at the point where the exception is thrown.

I know IPythons magic command `%debug` but this requires a Python script as argument. My current solution is insert `import IPython; IPython.embedd()` or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` manually, but I wonder if there is a better and noninstruive solution for this.

Is there a way to start the Python debugger automatically for command line tools which are implemented with *setuptools* entry point mechanism ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython launcher is a Python script itself, so just run it in Python debugger:

```
python -m pdb /usr/bin/ipython notebook
```